# Manipulating currentTime in HTML5 video

Tags: html, video

I'm trying to find an HTML5 video player that I can "not" use the progress bar to seek specific parts of the video, but have the video players horizontal area be relative to the length of the video.

For example, if I clicked in the middle of the video player div, I would be able to get the currentTime of the location I clicked.  I can get this through a mediaevent (http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html), but that assumes I'm clicking on the actual progress bar.

In the end, I'm looking to be able to select a portion of the video clip by clicking and dragging horizontally (kind of like how it's done in SoundCloud I believe).  I'm assuming I can do this with a layered div eventually.

Answer (score 0):

while it's not the full solution you're looking for, this sample demonstrates how to use a click on the `video` element to determine the position relative to the duration and adjust the Playhead.

You could adapt this to track two clicks, or a click and drag to set the start and end point

```
<body>

<p>Position video playhead in autoplaying video based on relative position of horizontal mouse click</p>

<video width="576" height="324" autoplay buffer="auto" id="video" onClick="getPositions()">
    <source src="big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<script>
    var vid=document.getElementById('video')
    var vidWidth = vid.width;
    var dur = 0;
    vid.addEventListener("durationchange", trackDuration, false);

    function trackDuration() {
        dur = vid.duration
    }

    function getPositions(ev) {
        if (ev == null) { ev = window.event }
        if (dur == 0) {
            // ignore if duration not set
        } else {
            _mouseX = ev.clientX;
            // set currentTime based on position of mouse
            vid.currentTime = dur * _mouseX / vidWidth
        }
    }
</script>

</body>
```